# Favorite icon for items in recyclerview doesn't work correctly with mvvm and firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, mvvm, android-recyclerview, kotlin-coroutines

I'm making a store app, each product is displayed in card inside a recyclerview, each card has a favorite button so every user has it's own favorite list.
I'm using firebase realtime database that has:

1. products (which has every product in the store)
2. users (which saves every user with it's own uid and his favorite list)

The functionality I want is that in the **StoreHomeFragment** it will check user's favorite list and make the favorite button checked based on it, also in the **ProductDetailsFragment** it checks if it's in favorite then make the favorite button checked.

Right now the **ProductDetailsFragment** functionality is working fine and saves the item to the user favorite list and also removes it and shows if the product is in favorite or not correctly.
**But** the **StoreHomeFragment** doesn't work as expected, every time I open the app all the products are unchecked even if they were in user's favorite list, then when I move to any product details and go back to StoreHomeFragment all the favorite icons would be checked. also isFavorite liveData observation won't  wait until my function in viewmodel and repo returns. I've tried so many before asking the question and searched a lot but I didn't able to solve the issue.

Since I'm using MVVM and repository for the firebase requests I need to make the best practice and clean architecture.

Here's the important parts of my code:

**ProductRepository**

```
class ProductRepository(
val database: FirebaseDatabase,
val storageRef: StorageReference
) {
suspend fun checkFavorite(productId: String): Boolean =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val deferredValue = CompletableDeferred<Boolean>()
        val databaseRef =
            database.reference.child("users")
                .child(FirebaseProfileService.getCurrentUserUid()!!)
                .child("favoritesList").child(productId)

        databaseRef.get().addOnCompleteListener {
            deferredValue.complete(
                (if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    it.result.value == productId
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "checkFavorite method is not successful")
                }) as Boolean
            )
        }
        return@withContext deferredValue.await()
     }
    }
```

**StoreHomeViewModel**

```
class StoreHomeViewModel(app: Application, private val repository: ProductRepository) :
AndroidViewModel(app) {

private val _isFavorite = MutableLiveData(false)
val isFavorite: LiveData<Boolean> get() = _isFavorite

fun checkFavorite(productId: String, isChecked: Boolean) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            _isFavorite.value = repository.checkFavorite(productId)
        } finally {
            if (isChecked && _isFavorite.value == true) {
                _isFavorite.value = true
            } else if (isChecked && _isFavorite.value == false) {
                addProductToFavorite(productId)
                _isFavorite.value = true
            } else if (!isChecked && _isFavorite.value == false) {
                _isFavorite.value = false
            } else {
                removeProductFromFavorite(productId)
                _isFavorite.value = false
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**StoreHomeFragment**

```
class StoreHomeFragment : Fragment() {

private val viewModel: StoreHomeViewModel by viewModel()
private lateinit var adapter: ProductsListAdapter

viewModel.isFavorite.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        adapter = ProductsListAdapter(ProductsListAdapter.ProductClickListener { product ->
            viewModel.onProductClicked(product)
        },ProductsListAdapter.IsFavoriteListener{ productId ->
            viewModel.checkFavorite(productId, isChecked)
        })
      }
```

**ProductListAdapter**

```
class ProductsListAdapter(
private val clickListener: ProductClickListener,
private var isFavorite: IsFavoriteListener
) :
ListAdapter<Product, ProductsListAdapter.ProductsListViewHolder>(DiffCallback()) {

class ProductsListViewHolder(private val binding: ProductListItemBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(
        product: Product,
        clickListener: ProductClickListener,
        isFavorite: IsFavoriteListener
    ) {
        binding.product = product
        binding.clickListener = clickListener
        binding.favIcon.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                buttonView.isChecked = isFavorite.onClick(product.id, true)
            } else {
                buttonView.isChecked = isFavorite.onClick(product.id, false)
            }
        }
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductsListViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val productItem = getItem(position)
    holder.bind(productItem, clickListener, isFavorite)
}

class ProductClickListener(val clickListener: (product: Product) -> Unit) {
    fun onClick(product: Product) = clickListener(product)
}

class IsFavoriteListener(val favoriteListener: (productId: String) -> Boolean) {
    fun onClick(productId: String, isChecked: Boolean) = favoriteListener(productId, isChecked)
}
```

I hope these info is enough to get the point and help me, Thank you.

Comment: "doesn't work well" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-android-app-using-firebase-part-1-4f305485e5d2) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireMag).

Comment: thanks @AlexMamo for your response, I've edited the question, hope it's clear to go.